# Xcode questions

Tags: discussion, site-scope

we are seeing some Xcode questions. Some are about the code being written and so are off topic here. However some are about keys to use e.g. [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85766/is-there-a-hand-tool-for-xcodes-storyboard-scrolling-without-scrollbars-pdf-s) and so are on topic here. However there are more Xcode users on Stack Overflow should we migrate these questions to Stack Overflow?

Comment: How does SO react to tool use questions? I'm not experienced enough with SO to know. If they're inclined to close tool use questions because they're not strictly about **programming** I'd say no, leave them here (assuming they're getting the care and attention they need here of course).

Comment: @IanC. Tool use questions are explicitly on topic for StackOverflow - see the FAQ which says "software tools commonly used by programmers"

Comment: I'd only migrate something if it wasn't getting attention here, otherwise it's on topic and a-okay to stay here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Broadly speaking Xcode is Apple software so any questions relating to the use of Xcode (key combinations, window handling etc.) clearly are on-topic enough to have a place in AD. There are enough developers hanging out here to help in answering these kind of questions.

This also means that for questions about Xcode usage both SO and AD might be the "right" place to ask. I don't think this will lead to any problems though, it's up to the asker to put the question onto whatever site he prefers (and hopefully not on both at once).

Answer (score 1):

If a question is on-topic here, it remains open. If it is off-topic, it gets closed. On-topic or off-topic, nothing gets migrated unless the OP requests is.

There are a number of questions that would be on-topic at more than one SE site. This is not a bug. If a question is asked here and it is on-topic here, here it is.

Comment: If off topic could the mods please also note that they will migrate it if asked not just close it.

Comment: No. Migration is not a feature I'm interested in advertising. I moderate this site, and don't particularly know or care what's on topic on other sites.

Comment: So a user will cut and paste a question from here to another so we get two questions - surely that is not an outcome we want

Comment: If someone requests migration, I'm willing to migrate, but as I said, I don't know or care what's on topic on sites other than Ask Different, so I'm not about to suggest migration to a site where I don't know what they want. From your account information, @Mark, it's clear you understand Super User and Stack Overflow. You're welcome to suggest migration where it's appropriate. I'm not qualified to do that. Also, more often than not, a question closed as off-topic here wouldn't be a good fit AS ASKED on other sites; while off-topic is an easy close reason, such questions usually need more work.

Comment: @Mark - In general, closing a question can sometimes result in migration, but not always. As a mod on another site, I always prefer it when other sites *ask us* before migrating a question; it sometimes saves us having to close a bad question when it arrives, which can be somewhat dizzying for new users.